# Get all Row and Column Positions of cells with strings starting with a pattern

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I'd like to know the locations (row and column indexes) of cells with strings starting with `Nr.`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['Nr.Example1',2,'CAT'],
                'B':[3,'Nr.Example2','Nr. Example3'],
                'C':[4,'Nr. example 4','DOG']})
```

Considering that, based on the dataframe above, the rows and columns of interest would be:

```
'Nr.Example1' = (0, 'A') or (0, 0)
'Nr.Example2' = (1, 'B') or (1, 1)
'Nr. Example3' = (2, 'B') or (2, 1)
'Nr. example 4' = (1, 'C') or (1, 2)
```

I'd like an output like:

```
locs = [(0, 'A'),(1, 'B'),(2, 'B'),(1, 'C')]
or
ilocs = [(0, 0),(1, 1),(2, 1),(1, 2)]
```

I could use

```
locs = df[df == 'Nr.Example1'].stack().index.tolist()
```

or

```
ilocs = np.where(df.values == 'Nr.Example1')
```

Run these lines of code looping over every single possibility and append the results into a list. HOWEVER, I don't know in advance all the possibilities. I do know that it will always begins with `Nr.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `stack` the DataFrame, and find indices of all records that `str.startswith` 'Nr.':

```
df.stack().str.startswith('Nr.')[lambda x: x==True].index.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[(0, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (1, 'C'), (2, 'B')]
```

---

Or with `numpy`:

```
np.argwhere(np.char.startswith(df.values.astype(str), 'Nr.'))
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 1]])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @perl ! But, what if instead of cells with strings starting with 'Nr.', I'd like to know the locations (row and column indexes) of cells with strings containing 'Example'? Using 'contains' instead of startswith  `df.stack().str.contains('Example')[lambda x: x==True].index.tolist()` I find the correct indexes. However, I don't know a function to use to replace the 'startswith' in the 'numpy-solution'.

Comment: @Allan As one of the options: `np.argwhere(df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('Example')).eq(True).values)`

Comment: Great! Thanks, @perl  !

Answer (score 1):

via `np.where`:

```
index = (np.where(df.astype(str).applymap(lambda x: x.startswith('Nr.')).values ==  True))
result = list(zip(index[0],index[1]))
```

**Output:**

```
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
```